# add multi language support in html javascript project

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, multilingual

I have project in spring boot 1.5 with jpa, on front-end is on HTML5 and javascript, i have used require.js as javascript framework. since in the beginning multi language was not required. Now I am feeling stuck, how to add i18 support as all text mess up all over in html as well as javascript.

Please help

Comment: Does this guide to internationalization help http://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-internationalization at all? Or this http://spr.com/part-4-internationalization-in-spring-boot/

Comment: Thanks Gavin! But I am not using template, these are html file with javascript(require.js), for example : for a pop-up text message , dynamically pop-up created with an embedded message, this is not coming from back-end, for better understanding requirement is like want <span th:text="#{lang.change}"></span> not in html but from javascript does this work with javascript too?

Comment: Did you look at https://github.com/Irrelon/jquery-lang-js ?

Comment: Thanks Gavin, It worked. Thankyou so much